# How can I get the current time in Godot?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm trying to make a digital clock in my game and need the current time (hours and minutes), formatted as so: `HH:MM:SS` How can I get the time necessary for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`Time`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_time.html) singleton, with the [`get_datetime_dict_from_system`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_time.html#class-time-method-get-datetime-dict-from-system) method  to get the time dictionary from the current system time.

```
# Get the time dictionary
var time = Time.get_time_dict_from_system()

print(time) # {day:X, dst:False, hour:xx, minute:xx, month:xx, second:xx, weekday:x, year:xxxx}
```

In your case, to format it as `HH:MM`, you can use the less noisy function [`get_time_dict_from_system`](https://get_time_dict_from_system) which only has hours, minutes, and seconds

```
var time = Time.get_time_dict_from_system()

# we can use format strings to pad it to a length of 2 with zeros, e.g. 01:20:12
print("%02d:%02d:%02d" % [time.hour, time.minute, time.second])
```

---

For older versions of Godot (`-3.4`), [`OS.get_time()`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_os.html#class-os-method-get-time) also works but in `3.5+` it's deprecated and `4.x` it's removed: